# Index for efficient full text search using "LIKE" syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, sql-like

I have an application which sends queries like the following to the database:

`x like '%abc%'`

I can't modify these queries, but I can index the underlying tables. Is there any way to put a full text index on a table such that double open-ended like queries can be performed without a full scan?

Comment: In order to use a Full Text Index, the query needs to use Full Text functions (`CONTAINS`).  There's nothing worth trying if you can't alter the query to not wildcard the left side of the `LIKE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to make `LIKE` predicates with wildcards avoid a table-scan so they perform well for full-text search.  You must use Oracle Text features and modify your queries to use text-searching predicates.

See [Oracle® Text Application Developer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14217/toc.htm)